# Create a single commit for multiple cherry picks

Tags: git

I am trying to cherry-pick a list of commits in a for loop and whilst doing it, I encounter a lot of merge conflicts which I have handled as below.

```
git checkout target_branch
for cpHash in "some random list of commits"; do
   git chery-pick --no-commit $cpHash
   git ls-files -u | cut -f2 | sort -u | xargs -i{} git checkout --. 
   theirs {}
   git add -A .
   git commit -m "some text"
done
```

As mentioned above, the git commit inside the loop is just to clean up the repo so that the next cherry pick occurs on that version, however it is trivial, it  is just of git history.
What I need is to club all these commits within the for loop into ONE SINGLE COMMIT which I will track in our application.

How can I acheive this?
I dont intend to use git rebase as the repo is shared across multiple teams.

Thanks.
Kumarjit

Comment: Record the first base commit, $base. After all the cherry-picks are done, `git reset --soft $base && git commit -m foo`.

Comment: Since $base is the FIRST COMMIT of the loop, shouldn't I use "git reset --soft $base~1" instead so that I revert the staging area to where it was before the the loop started?? Also, wouldn't this allow me to re-commit for the changes made by the $base commit?  Thank you.

Comment: The base I mean is the head of target_branch before the loop starts.

Comment: Noted. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to ammend the commits inside the for loop, e.g.

```
git checkout target_branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "final commit message"
for cpHash in "some random list of commits"; do
   git chery-pick --no-commit $cpHash
   git ls-files -u | cut -f2 | sort -u | xargs -i{} git checkout --. 
   theirs {}
   git add -A .
   git commit --amend --no-edit
done
```

And by the way, a rebase is nothing but a few consequent cherry-picks.

Comment: after that you can make `git rebase -i branch_name` to merge to one commit

Comment: @ alflunx shouldn't the following line be at the end of the for loop?  git commit --allow-empty - m "some message"

Comment: @KumarjitGhosh No, the idea is that we first create an empty commit and then in the loop we amend to that commit (instead of creating new commits).

Comment: @alflunx got it.. went through the git amend documentations..  thank you once again

Comment: @alflunx got it.. went through the git amend documentations..  thank you once again